# SignalR 403 status code on websocket transport handshake

Tags: websocket, signalr, owin, signalr-hub

I am mapping signalR in Web Api by following code in Startup.cs class

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        ConfigureAuth(app);
        app.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {
            map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
            {
                EnableDetailedErrors= true,
                EnableJSONP=true
            };
            map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        });
    }
```

Along with it i used Bearer token authentication and cookies authentication in Web Api by following code

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            CookieHttpOnly = true,
            CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest,
            CookiePath = "/",
            CookieDomain = "xxxx.cloudapp.net",
        });
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        PublicClientId = "self";
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        };

        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            Provider = new QueryStringOAuthBearerProvider("Token")
        });
```

Web Api is on different domain so i enabled Cors for Api calls by following code

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var cors = new    EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:8080,http://www.myweb.com,http://myweb.com", "*", "*");
        cors.SupportsCredentials = true;
        config.EnableCors(cors);   
     ......
     ......
     }
```

Now, while connecting from client side, I am getting following error in console

[image: SignalR 403 status code]

Here is response that i am getting in corresponding to websocket handshake

[image]

Please guide on this.

Comment: Be sure you have eneabled/support websocket in your Web Api app(server).

Comment: it is enabled in cloud service

Comment: not sure if this is related to this but if you are using framework 4.5 do you have set 
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" /> 
in web.config > appSettings tag

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I've had the same problem, so for future reference if anyone else stumbles upon it...

Somehow this:

```
CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest,
```

is the problem.
It doesnt work as it should (don't know why)...

This is my cookie configuration:

```
            builder.Register(ctx => new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
                CookieName = "xxx",
                CookieHttpOnly = false, // Kako bi mu mogli pristupiti iz Javascripta
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                LoginPath = PathString.Empty,
                LogoutPath = PathString.Empty,
                SlidingExpiration = true,
#if DEBUG
                CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest,
#else
                CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
#endif
                CookieDomain = "localhost"
            });
```

and this is my token configuration

```
            builder.Register(ctx => new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/authorize"),
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/token"),
                ApplicationCanDisplayErrors = true,
                Provider = ctx.Resolve<ApplicationOAuthProvider>(),
                //RefreshTokenProvider = ctx.Resolve<ApplicationRefreshTokenProvider>(),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
#if DEBUG
                AllowInsecureHttp = true
#endif
            });
```

After hosting my application on HTTPS localhost it automagicaly worked.
Why? Still don't know :P